# Always same problem with new GPUs

Tags: boot, nvidia, screen, gpu

Guys I am having same problem all the time year after year after year.

When new GPU is out and I am trying to install Ubuntu on new PC I never can't get it to boot in to GUI. It's always same thing, black screen with Nouveau error. If I am not mistaken Nouveau is some sort of driver that is in use during post and if new GPU is not yet supported by this Nouveau I am screwed.

Now I do know there is few ways to install Ubuntu. I remember old msdos looking shell and I really have no problem with it as long as I can get Ubuntu installed and then update GPU drivers with latest available and boot to proper GUI.

Is there a tutorial for this problem I can find somewhere? I am sure I am not only person with Nvidia 2000 series GPU trying to install Ubuntu.
Thank you so much guys !!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you are getting new Nvidia GPUs, is probably to go with the Nvidia proprietary drivers, as they will probably have support built-in in advance, or at least quicker than Mesa can update Nouveau. IIRC, Nvidia does not help with the maintenance of Nouveau, but AMD does do a significant amount of the development for new open source drivers, generally making them an easy time with Linux, but Nvidia has been getting better, or so I hear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input but I think you missed my point. Once system is installed and up and running, sure thing installing proprietary Nvidia drivers is the way to go. My question is HOW to do it. Because right now I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on a system using 2080ti and I can't Installation GUI is not loading. So how do I do it ? How do I install Ubuntu with unsupported GPU because like I said in OP Nouveau is crashing on boot of the USB installation media.

Comment: @XAKEP If you cannot get Ubuntu installed, I would recommend installing it to the drive on another computer, or via another GPU/onboard graphics. If you still cannot boot into the system with the new GPU (likely), then you'll have to try and install the drivers without the GPU installed.

Frankly, the system *should* fall back to older, universal video output formats (Vega IIRC, IDK), so I'm betting you're not running into a software issue at all. Check that you have enough power for your system, and that all the components are stable.